# Why isn't drop down changing based on other value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Anyone care to take a stab?

I have a form with the below.  When the user selects the "disabled" option in #frmcomments, I'd like #frmstatus to change to the option value of private.

```
<label for="type">Comments:</label>
<select class="sort-select" id="frmcomments" name="frmcomments">
    <option value="enabled">Allow Comments</option>
    <option value="disabled">No Comments</option>
</select>



<label for="type">Status:</label>
<select class="sort-select" id="frmstatus" name="frmstatus">
    <option value="public">Anyone can see</option>
    <option value="private">Only I can see</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following jquery, but it's failing?

```
$('#frmcomments').change(function() {
    var thistype = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    if(thistype=="disabled") {
        $("#frmstatus").val("private");
    }

    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HzrKT/

Comment: Me as well; http://jsfiddle.net/UnkBV/1/

Comment: Bizarre.  If I check the form values upon submit, it shows the value as being private -- but the display doesn't change.

Comment: Are you seeing it in a particular browser or a framework not mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `thistype` value. You should be able to call `val()` on the `select` and you shouldn't have to call `.find(":selected")` to get the selected list item.

Comment: If I throw an alert to output thistype, it shouts disabled.  Same if I remove the .find(":selected") piece.

Comment: @Mike: If this answer helped you, you are more then welcome to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#frmcomments').change(function() {
    var thistype = $(this).val();

    if(thistype=="disabled") {
        $("#frmstatus").val("private").change();
    }
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var thistype = $(this).find(":selected").val();
```

try this

```
var thistype = $(this).val();
```